# Mysql / Ruby Sequel last insert ID value, what method?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I just want to get the last_insert_id() using Ruby's Sequel:

```
insertret = @con.run("INSERT INTO `wv_persons` ( `id` ) VALUES ( NULL )")
pp insertret.inspect # returns "nil", expected that..
last_insert_id = @con.run("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS last_id;")
pp last_insert_id.inspect # returns "nil", should be an ID
```

The SELECT query should return the last_id but .run does not return it. What method should I use instead?

**Solution:** (thanks to Josh Lindsey)

```
last_insert_id = @con[:wv_persons].insert({})
last_insert_id = last_insert_id.to_s
puts "New person ["+ last_insert_id  +"]"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Dataset#insert](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#M000421) method should return the last insert id:

```
DB[:wv_persons].insert({})
```

Will insert the default values and return the id.

[Database#run](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#M000401) will always return `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, [Database#insert](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-insert) is not guaranteed to return the id of the last inserted record.

From the documentation: "...Inserts values into the associated table. *The returned value is generally the value of the primary key for the inserted row*, but that is **adapter dependent.**"

Answer (score 1):

The sequel gem **is supposed to return the id of newly inserted records** but as others said:

- the returned value is **adapter dependent**

also i'd like to add...

- isn't sure what to return when faced with a **composite primary key**

You can get around this by telling sequel exactly what should be returned using the `#returning` method.

For instance:

`DB[:posts].returning(:id).insert(category_id: 5, id: 1, ...)`

will return `[{id: 1}]`

and

`DB[:posts].returning(:id, :category_id).insert(category_id: 5, id: 1, ...)`

will return `[{id: 1, category_id: 5}]`